# Web Api Security - DNS Substitution

Tags: asp.net, dns, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Currently im trying to make a license server based on ASPNET Web Api.

Basicly the licensed software wont be under my control, hence i need a way to control usage.

I see one problem however, in case the license server responds with json or an statuscode saying a license check is ok, the format could be sniffed on the software location and a service could be created to respond likewise (by changing their dns, so that the hardcoded domain is pointed to their service instead.

Any help in this area is appreciated, as if i recall correct, ssl is only point to point

Answer (score 0):

You could have your application host a wild card DNS record.  Meaning an A record that looks something like:

*.foobar    86400   IN  A   1.2.3.4

thus requests to the host could include a different host name:

ab34dd8993aedf455c.foobar.mydomain.com

The code in front of the name could be used to authenticate the request based on time/source ip/json in request.

Regards

Frank

Comment: I should have mentioned that the host name used for the HTTP 1.1 request is accessible in the host header for the Web request.